# A way to indicate method initiated/fail/success with annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Is there a way in Java/Spring with annotations to achieve the following?

For example I have a method:

```
public void deleteObject(Object object) {
    delete(object);
}
```

I want to send 2 audit events: one when method starts, and second - if method finishes successfully or throws exception.

Actually, I can do it like this:

```
public void deleteObject(Object object) {
    sendAuditEvent("Started deletion of object");
    try {
        delete(object);
        sendAuditEvent("Finished deleting of object successfully");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        sendAuditEvent("Finished deleting object with exception");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to do it with annotations? I'd prefer to keep the auditing logic separately and not autowire any beans for sending audit events.

The only thing coming top my mind is to do something like this:

```
public void deleteObject(Object object) {
    startedDeleting(object);
    delete(object);
}

@SomeAnnotationOnStartOfMethod
public void startedDeleting(Object object) {
   //do nothing 
}

public void delete(Object object) {
   try {
       businessLogicMethodToDelete(object);
       methodOnSuccess(object);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       methodOnException(object);
       throw ex;
   }
}

@SomeAnnotationOnSuccess
public void methodOnSuccess(Object object) {
   //do nothing 
}

@SomeAnnotationOnFailure
public void methodOnException(Object object) {
   //do nothing 
}
```

But that looks not nice to me.

What could be a better design solution here?

Comment: What you are looking for is call Aspect Oriented Programming. [AspectJ](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj) and [Spring AOP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop) are two common libraries for AOP.

Comment: Thanks!! Silly me, couldn’t ask properly Google to point me there :( And now I see that’s exactly it! Care to make an answer, I’ll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

The most commonly used tools to solve this kind of problems are:

- [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) (cf. also the tutorial on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj)),
- [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#aop) (cf. also the tutorial on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop))